# Backbone Js Load application in parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am building a small application in backbone.js

It consists of a router, a number of basic views and models etc, and a blog.

With regards to the blog, the contents of the posts will be held in a db, for the other pages though, the content is contained within underscore templates. This is what my router looks like:

```
$(function() {
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
  '': 'home',
  'home' : 'home',
  'portfolio' : 'portfolio'
}
});

var homeView = new HomeView({ el: $("#container") });
var portfolioView = new PortfolioView({ el: $("#container") });

var router = new Router();
router.on('route:home', function () {
    homeView.render();
});

router.on('route:portfolio', function () {
    portfolioView.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Currently I just have the home view and the portfolio view. My concern is, will the entire app be loaded when going to my site address? Although its a small application is there a way to break it up into pieces so for example, the portfolioview and all the data (the images are my main concern) associated with it, will only be downloaded when navigating to 'portfolio'? What is the best way to handle this, and is it even necessary for a relatively small app (a few pages and a blog)? Or am I in fact mistaken and backbone already does this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating View instances when actually you don't need them? Why not creating them within your route handlers?

Comment: I didnt want my route file to get too bloated, and I may need them in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally unnecessary to worry about this for a small app, or even for most large apps. Just send all the JS/templates down the wire (ideally minified and concatenated in production). The point of single-page apps is that you don't *have* to hit the network to pull in HTML/JS/other assets when navigation occurs. You definitely shouldn't be trying to lazy-load your templates across the network.

As far as images go, they'll already come down the network only when you actually add an `<img>` tag to the DOM.